# R Studio – How to reverse strike through?

Tags: r, rstudio

After reopening a .R in RStudio, everything all the code is struck through in red.  How can I reverse it?

[image: Screenshot of RStudio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit Shift+Option+C by mistake, which is the shortcut for "Run the current Sweave/Rmd chunk" in RSTudion. Source: [Support-RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts)